# "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time" while adding data to dictionary in swift 3, works fine in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

```
let parameters : [String : AnyObject] = [
    "address" :      txtAddress.text ?? "",
    "person_name" :  txtAuthorName.text ?? "",
    "person_image" : imgUrl ?? "", 
    "book_title" :   txtBookTitle.text ?? "", 
    "dedicated_to" : txtDedicatedTo.text ?? "" , 
    "person_about" : txtAboutTheAuthor.text ?? "",
    "is_published" : false,
    "recipes" : recipeArr  ?? ""]
```

This is the code for adding data to dictionary. Works fine on *Swift2.3*.

**Swift 3 Compiler says to break the expression to sub-expressions.**

Kindly suggest an apt solution.

Comment: Replace `AnyObject` with `Any` (the "too complex to be solved" hides an actual compile time error: try compiling your example as is with a few less members).

Comment: doesn't solves my problem actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it in the below manner worked fine for me

```
var dictionary =  [String: Any]()
   dictionary["key1"] = value1
   dictionary["key2"] = value2
   //...
```